# Need to convert Image file back to X Y co-ordinate format

Tags: c#-4.0

I am drawing an signature like this as given below and taking  X Y cordinate and saving it to the arry list.

```
Bitmap bmp;

        //Graphics object 
        Graphics graphics;

        //Pen object
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);

        // Array List of line segments
        ArrayList pVector = new ArrayList();

        //Point object
        Point lastPoint = new Point(0, 0);

 protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);

            // process if currently drawing signature
            if (!drawSign)
            {
                // start collecting points
                drawSign = true;

                // use current mouse click as the first point
                lastPoint.X = e.X;
                lastPoint.Y = e.Y;
            }

        }

 protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            // process if drawing signature
            if (drawSign)
            {
                if (graphics != null)
                {
                    // draw the new segment on the memory bitmap
                    graphics.DrawLine(pen, lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y, e.X, e.Y);
                    pVector.Add(lastPoint.X + " " + lastPoint.Y + " " + e.X + " " + e.Y);

                    // update the current position
                    lastPoint.X = e.X;
                    lastPoint.Y = e.Y;

                    // display the updated bitmap
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
```

Using the arrylist (pVector) I am saving the values to the database  as string(singature ) and aslo as image as given  below

```
//Saving value to Database
ArrayList arrSign = new ArrayList();
                arrSign = this.signatureControl.getPVector();

                string singature = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < arrSign.Count; i++)
                {
                    singature = singature + arrSign[i].ToString() + "*";
                }


 the string singature  wiil be like this 
60 46 59 48*59 48 59 51*59 51 59 53*59 53 60 49*60 49 61 44*61 44 62 38*62 38 64 31*64 31 67 23*67 23 70 14*70 14 72 10*72 10 75 3*75 3 77 -2*77 -2 76 2*76 2 75 6*75 6 72 17*72 17 71 24*71 24 69 31*69 31 68 46*68 46 67 59*67 59 68 71*68 71 69 79*69 79 70 86*70 86 71 89*71 89 71 93*71 93 71 95*71 95 71 97*71 97 70 95*70 95 69 88*69 88 68 81*68 81 69 77*69 77 69 68*69 68 71 60

//Saving as Image file

   Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
                                 string[] arrStr = (signature.Split('*'));

                                 Graphics graphics;
                                 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 200);

                                 graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                                 graphics.Clear(Color.White);

                                 for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.Length - 2; i++)
                                 {
                                     string[] strArr = new string[4];
                                     strArr = ((arrStr[i].ToString()).Split(' '));
                                     graphics.DrawLine(pen, Convert.ToInt32(strArr[0].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(strArr[1].ToString()),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(strArr[2].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(strArr[3].ToString()));
                                 }

                                 string pathToCopyImage = systemBus.TempFile;

                                 bmp.Save(pathToCopyImage + "\\" + dsReportDetails.Tables["tblDelivery"].Rows[0]["PKDelivery"].ToString() + "_Signature.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                                 bmp.Dispose();
```

My problem is that after Saving the signature as Image file I am not able to convert it back to arrylist like the one that i am used to save the value in the database.
ie I need to convert the image file back to as given below format

```
60 46 59 48*59 48 59 51*59 51 59 53*59 53 60 49*60 49 61 44*61 44 62 38*62 38 64 31*64 31 67 23*67 23 70 14*70 14 72 10*72 10 75 3*75 3 77 -2*77 -2 76 2*76 2 75 6*75 6 72 17*72 17 71 24*71 24 69 31*69 31 68 46*68 46 67 59*67 59 68 71*68 71 69 79*69 79 70 86*70 86 71 89*71 89 71 93*71 93 71 95*71 95 71 97*71 97 70 95*70 95 69 88*69 88 68 81*68 81 69 77*69 77 69 68*69 68 71 60
```

Will any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

It is not very easy to get your "signature string" back from image so you can just add you "string signature" to saved image as a metadata tag of image (as a Description for example). So then you read your image back you don't need to recognize "signature string" from image, you can just read it from metadata as a string. Msdn has a nice article about image metadata and api to work with them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx

By the way, your code for concatenating "signature string" is slow and memory consuming. It is better to use StringBuilder in such situations in .Net. And overall strings are not the best data structure to store list of points. But it depends on requirements for your app.